# Limit $\lim_{x\to0} \left(\frac1e(1+x)^{1/x}\right) ^{1/\sin x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

The question goes like this 
Limit

$$\lim_{x\to0} \left(\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}}{e}\right)^{1/\sin x}$$

Any help is welcome .

Comment: Are you familiar with the logarithmic evaluation of limits, @Simar?

Comment: Ya kind of. This is a case of 1^infinity^infinity . so do we take log twice ?

Comment: Maple produces the answer $e^{-1/2}$ and Maple Tutor LimitMethods shows the solution step by step. See [screenshot](http://rapidshare.com/files/2466184049/limit.docx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shortcuts are possible, but one very standard approach to limits of this kind is take the logarithm. Let $L$ be the desired limit. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\ln L&=\ln\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}}e\right)^{1/\sin x}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\ln\left(\left(\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}}e\right)^{1/\sin x}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac1{\sin x}\cdot\ln\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}}e\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)^{1/x}-1}{\sin x}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)-x}{x\sin x}
\end{align*}$$

where the interchange of the log and the limit is possible because the log is a continuous function. The limit succumbs easily to a couple of applications of l’Hospital’s rule.

Don’t forget, though, that after you’ve found $\ln L$, you’ll have to exponentiate to get $L$ itself.

Comment: @Ron: Yes, I caught the dropped log almost as soon as I hit Post.

Comment: One shouldn't separate the fraction — use L'Hospital's rule for the whole fraction.

Comment: @Ruslan: Indeed one shouldn’t. Apparently I’m not quite awake yet, but it’s fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

If we assume the limit exists and is equal to $L$, then

$$\log{L} = \frac{(1/x)\log{(1+x)}-1}{\sin{x}} $$

The easiest way forward is to Taylor expand numerator and denominator - numerator should be expanded to the $x^2$ term.  The end result is

$$L = \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(x)=\left(\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}}{e}\right)^{1/\sin x}$$ Then $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\ln f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\sin x}\left(\frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}-1\right)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\sin x}\left(-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}-\cdots\right)=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Since $\ln(\cdot)$ is continuous, we get $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$$

Answer (score 1):

First note that *by definition* of exponentiation
$$ \left(\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}}{e}\right)^{1/\sin x}
=\exp\left(\frac1{\sin x}\ln\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}}{e}\right)
=\exp\left(\frac1{\sin x}\left(\frac1x\ln(1+x)-1\right)\right)
$$
Now you can work your way from inside out using l'Hopital (or Taylor if you prefer)

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\left(\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}}e\right)^{1/\sin x}=e^{\frac1{\sin x}\left(\log(1+x)^{1/x}-1\right)}$$

So it suffices to evaluate the limit of the exponent above (why?). Note that

$$(1+x)^{1/x}=e^{\frac1x\log(1+x)}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}e\;,\;\;\text{by l'Hospital's rule, so :}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(1+x)^{1/x}-1}{\sin x}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(-\frac1{x^2}\log(1+x)+\frac1{x(1+x)}\right)\cdot\frac1{\cos x}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-(1+x)\log(1+x)}{x^2(1+x)\cos x}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\log(1+x)-1}{2x(1+x)\cos x+x^2\cos x-x^2(1+x)\sin x}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0}-\frac1{(1+x)\left(2\cos x+6x\cos x-4x(1+x)\sin x-2x^2\sin x-x^2(1+x)\cos x\right)}=$$

$$=-\frac1{1\cdot2}=-\frac12$$

and thus, finally,  the limit is ...